# A movie about getting to a fake utopian planet / virtual environment

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

- A movie about getting to a utopian planet that found out to be a fake one, instead the people were connected to a machine, that took them to a virtual environment, that had the name of the said utopian planet
- Earth is in some sort of problem and humanity is living in a space station or on the fake utopian planet
- The main character is a woman, trying to survive
- The space station is run by a some sort of big corporation

Which movie is this?

Comment: Any idea when this may have been made - for example, when you saw it would exclude more recent movies.

Comment: We've got a [dedicated site](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/) for these questions.

Answer (score 7):

The movie is [Cargo](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0381940/), in case you never found it. I found this forum searching for the same film..

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_%282009_film%29):

> Lindbergh realizes that Portmann doesn't trust her and restrains her too, revealing to her that **Rhea is a giant virtual reality simulation on a station** in orbit around the actual, uninhabitable, planet.

Answer (score 0):

Except for the big corporation aspect, that describes an episode of the original Star Trek series:  [*For the World Is Hollow and I Have Touched the Sky* (1968)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_the_World_Is_Hollow_and_I_Have_Touched_the_Sky) which no doubt inspired many similar stories.

Comment: I was going to say it describes many TV episodes. There is one just like this in Stargate, Outer Limits and a few others.